# Can't create correct folder structure in my MSI

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

My application stores data in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Company\Product\foo
```

However if I use **Application.CommonAppDataPath** in my code, it is appending the assembly version on the end pf the path. eg

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Company\Product\foo\1.0.2.0
```

This means that my app cant find the data I was expecting. I can manipulate my code to strip off the last folder, but what I'd really like to do is to have my MSI create the appropriate assembly versioned folder.

I have tried;

```
[CommonAppDataFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[Version]\
[CommonAppDataFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[ProductVersion]\
```

But neither gives me the correct structure. (In fact one doesn't create a folder and the other creates one based on the MSI version).

So is there a way of creating the appropriate folder through the msi, or do I need to resort to either parsing the AppDataPath, or having my app create the version folder and the supporting structures it needs?

Comment: Never install user data, create it via the application. That way it is always decoupled from interference from the MSI on install, uninstall, patching, etc... You can create the base folder by using a CreateFolder entry in the MSI file, but the data itself should never be installed - it causes only trouble.

Comment: A common way to create your application data folder(s) is actually to copy it from templates in Program Files and initiate it per user. This can cause the need to tweak settings, and you can implement this along these lines: http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=21552

Answer (score 0):

If you define `ProductVersion` property in your MSI, then it would work. (Or you can call it whatever you like.)

As far as I know there's no standard property in Windows Installer which has the version of the assembly. Hence you have to create it yourself.

The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to manually update this version property in Setup project when the version of your assembly changes.

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest, how do I define additional properties in my MSI?

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure how it's done in Visual Studio, in WiX you just add a new [`<Property>`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_property.htm) element. Basically you add a new row to Property table of the MSI.

Answer (score 0):

ProductVersion is a predefined installer property which stores your MSI version. This is a much more reliable version for your application data folder path than the assembly version.

Most installers write this version somewhere (for example the registry) and then the installed application reads and uses it.

It also has more sense this way. You are installing a version of your product, not the version of a file. If the assembly version stays the same in two different installer versions, some conflicts may occur.

Comment: Thanks. What you said makes sense with regards to more complicated installs (and I should follow best practice). I'll need to rethink a couple of things, but then thats always the way!